creacion de pagina web con hostinger
estoy planeando desarrollar mi primer proyecto de página web y publicarlo en internet. Mi idea es utilizar React y Tailwind CSS para el frontend, mientras que el backend lo haré con Node.js, y para la base de datos usaré MySQL Server.
El proyecto será una página de automóviles, donde todos los datos se almacenarán en la base de datos. Estos datos se cargarán al backend y luego se enviarán al frontend para su visualización.
Mi pregunta es: ¿es posible alojar todo este proyecto (frontend, backend y base de datos) en Hostinger para que la página web sea pública? ¿Qué pasos debo seguir para hacerlo correctament

En hostinger? si no veo el problema, te dan todo un plan para alojar, y puedes consultar con ellos lo que necesitas y lo que ofrecen.

Si se puede, pero hay consideraciones. Hostinger no soporta NodeJS en los planes de web hosting simple: Ver Hostinger y NodeJS. Tendrás que arrendar un VPS, lo cual es un poquito más caro, y tendrás que administrar y configurar el servidor tu mismo. Si hicieras el backend en PHP te ahorras esa complicación o bien, buscar otro hosting con NodeJS.
